# Call kernel32.dll from website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web

I have created website  project, and am using IIS version 6 as the web server when developing. When I try to debug this method  (createfile)  bellow in order to read from USB .

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
        const uint GENERIC_WRITE = (0x40000000);
        const uint FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME = 0x00090018;
        const uint FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME = 0x0009001c;
        const uint FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME = 0x00090020;

        bool success = false;
        int intOut;
        string deviceId = @"\\.\H:";
        long DiskSize = 2056320000;

        SafeFileHandle diskHandle = CreateFile(deviceId, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (diskHandle.IsInvalid)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(deviceId + " open error.");

            Debug.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            return 0;
        }
```

I get this error num (5=access denied), but it works fine in other types of projects like (windows forms , console application , asp project ).

How can this be solved?

thank you in advance

Comment: ASP.NET user **does not have such permissions** (imagine if because of a bug on your site an attacker can access disk aa such low level...) so you can't do it unless you **elevate its privileges** (highly highly **discouraged**, much better to **put that logic in a service** than some **IPC** to complete requests)

Answer (score 0):

the solution has been found, we just need to give permissions to the application pool by changing the identity property to (Local system)